# Kony - rowTemplate returns a string on Android instead object with references to widgets in template

Tags: android, ios, temenos-quantum

When I try to access the rowTemplate of a Segment2 widget in Kony 7.3 it returns a string on Android instead of an object, making it impossible to assign a gesture recognizer to the row template. Here's my assignment:

`this.view.segDayViewCards.rowTemplate.flexDayViewCard.addGestureRecognizer(constants.GESTURE_TYPE_SWIPE, setupSwipe, this.onCardSwipe);`

This happens inside of the controller.js file that is generated when you create a form. `onCardSwipe` is a function that is also in my controller.

This works just as it should on iOS, but causes the app to crash on Android because `flexDayViewCard` is undefined since `rowTemplate` is a string.

Here's the comparison of what I see on Android vs iOS

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj3fO.png)

[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVGQa.png)

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you include a code snippet that gives context to the single line in your post. This helps others better understand (and probably reproduce) the problem. And always include a stacktrace for the crash.

Comment: I'm not sure how to access a stack trace from a crash. Are you familiar with kony? If so, do you know how to find one?

Comment: You have to run DDMS for accessing the stacktraces. You can find DDMS in installed android SDK folder. DDMS window will show the list of connected devices and you have to select device running the application for getting logs.

Comment: Why are you trying to add gesture recog. at run time and why not at the time of developing template in kony visualiser or kony studio?